# Обработка клика вне элемента | JAVA

Tags: java, android

Как обработать клик вне элемента в Android?

Comment: Вне какого элемента? Нужно больше информации. Приложите код какой-то.

Comment: [`onInterceptTouchEvent`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9586032/android-difference-between-onintercepttouchevent-and-dispatchtouchevent)

Comment: То что вне одного элемента, есть внутри другого.

Comment: @SergeiBuvaka, одного из layout. Допустим, LinearLayout.

Answer (score 0):

Если вы хотите вызывать onClick из активити без клика на кнопку тогда:

activity_main.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!-- layout elements -->
<Button android:id="@+id/mybutton"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:text="Click me!"
android:onClick="myFancyMethod" />
<!-- even more layout elements -->
```

MainActivity.java

```
Button btn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.mybutton);

btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    myFancyMethod(v);
}
});

// some more code

 public void myFancyMethod(View v) {
// does something very interesting
}
```

Comment: Даже не близко к тому, что я спросил.